# Routing/Navigation bug in Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have an Angular JS app and I would like to use it with Cordova. In the browser the Angular app works fine. On Cordova however, the navigation is very buggy. I tried the ngRoute and the ui-router methods, but both show similar problem.

The problem is as follows: I go to a state (newsitem), the controller of a newsitem fetches the local storage (made in a service where externally JSON feed is loaded), so far so good. The item is showing properly.

However, when I scrolll down, I automatically return to the / state.

M code is as follows:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'pages/homepage.html',
      controller: 'homeNewsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        newsList: function (newsItemFactory) {
          return newsItemFactory.getNewsItems();
        }
      }
    })
    .state('newsitem', {
      url: '/newsitem:id',
      templateUrl: 'pages/newsitem.html',
      controller: 'newsItemCtrl'
    })
});

app.controller('homeNewsCtrl', function ($scope, newsList) {

  $scope.count = 1;
  $scope.newsItems = newsList.data;


  window.localStorage['News'] = JSON.stringify(newsList.data);
  var newsLocal = window.localStorage['News'];
  var parsedNewsItems = JSON.parse(newsLocal);

  $scope.mainID = parsedNewsItems[0].id;
  $scope.mainTitle = parsedNewsItems[0].title.rendered;
  $scope.mainImage = parsedNewsItems[0].better_featured_image.source_url;

});

app.controller('newsItemCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, commentItems) {
  var postid = $stateParams.id;
  var newsLocal = window.localStorage['News'];
  var parsedNewsItem = JSON.parse(newsLocal);
  $scope.newsItem = parsedNewsItem[postid];
  $scope.commentItems = [];

  commentItems.getComments($scope.newsItem.id, null).then(function (response) {
    $scope.commentItems = response.data;
    console.log($scope.commentItems);
  });
});
```

homepage.html

```
<div class="homenews">
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li bindonce ng-repeat="item in newsItems track by $index" class="newsitem">
      <a href="#/newsitem{{$index}}">
        <div class="newsimage"
             style="background-image: url('{{ item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url }}');"></div>
        <h2 ng-bind-html="item.title.rendered"></h2>
        <span class="comment-count">{{item.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

newsitem.html

```
<div class="item single">
  <div class="newsimage" style="background-image: url('{{ newsItem.better_featured_image.source_url }}');">
    <h2 ng-bind-html="newsItem.title.rendered"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h3 class="meta">{{newsItem.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</h3>

    <div class="news-item">
      <p ng-bind-html="newsItem.content.rendered"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comments-container">
  <div class="comments">
    <ul class="unstyled" infinite-scroll='loadMoreComments(1)'
        infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
      <li class="item" ng-repeat="comment in commentItems">
        <h4>{{comment.author_name}} <span class="right">{{comment.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</span></h4>

        <div ng-bind-html="comment.content.rendered"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```